# pass props to sub tab components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt89H.png)I am tryin to pass this.props.navigation to another tab but it returns null, I nee to use scrollabletabbarview and react-navigation/stacknavigator component. I want to tap inside tab and open a new stack

```
 render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return             <ScrollableTabView  style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',padding:0}}
        tabBarActiveTextColor="#333"
        tabBarBackgroundColor="yellow"
        tabStyle={{ paddingTop: 0 }}
        navigator={this.props.navigation}
        contentProps={this.props}
        renderTabBar={() => <TabBar underlineColor="#333" tabBadgeColor="#333333"/>}>
            <Pagehg tabLabel={{label: "dsadsa!"}} label="Hoşgeldin!"/>
            <Chats tabLabel={{label: "dsa dsa", badge: 3,props:navigate}} label="Page #2 aka Long!" navigation={navigate}/>
```

Comment: are u using react-navigation?

Comment: @vijayst yes... with https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

Comment: "it returns null" What returns null? Where?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  have updated the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')